# BSOD crashes after a freeze period of 100% Highest Active Time while the Hard Disk actually appears to be idle

Tags: hard-drive, bsod

After a few BSoD crashes of my Windows 7 that follow a period of semi-frozen environment, I have started monitoring my Resource Monitor to try to catch the culprit in act.

The symptoms are:

- The machine just freezes, and starts being non-responsive to almost anything. In the last incident, I was monitoring the Resource Monitor, and was able to move the mouse and click on the items in the window, but the rest of the system was non-responding (ctrl + shift + esc for Task manager, crtl + alt + delete for the same, nothing...).
- If I move the mouse outside of the borders of the active window (in this situation, the Resource Monitor) the cursor changes into the hourglass.
- When the system hung, the percentages slowly faded to non-usage, the green lines started disappearing from the graphs, but the Highest active time (the blue hard drive line) remained stuck at 100% all the time.
- After 1-2 mins of unresponsiveness, the system BSoD-ed.

This is the screenshot taken a few seconds before the crash:
[image: few seconds before the crash]
(the blue line is stuck to the top of the Hard Drive graph)

What is this blue line of hard drive activity and how can I see whats causing that activity while everything else seems to stand still? Do you have any idea what these symptoms point to?

The frequency of the BSOD crashes are about 1-2 every 4-5 hours, so a couple of times per day, with no apparent connection to the stress of the machine at the time.

Answer (score 2):

From the description so far I'd say you're looking at disk failures. The disk shows busy not because it is constantly handling requests (plural), but because a single request isn't completing.

Check your system event log for errors in the Disk category. In Explorer, right-click on `Computer` and select `Manage` to get to Computer Management (or just `Run` `compmgmt.msc`). In the left pane, drill down to `System Tools | Event Viewer | Windows Logs | System`. Look for "Error"-level events from the source "Disk". If you see any at all, that's a problem.

Something else you should do is look at the minidump files to try to at least find out what the "bugcheck code" is. OSR has a free "dump reader" tool [here](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze) that will spit out the results of the debugger's famous !analyze -v command for a dump you upload. Post a couple of them as edits to your question. Or, you can put a few of your minidumps in some public place like Dropbox, post a link, and people like me will look at them for you. The minidumps should be in `\Windows\minidump` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After checking the Events and noticing Warnings about the Etron USB drivers I've updated all of my drivers and I'm waiting for the crash to happen again. I didn't find any other clues in the log.